# Not able to provide deicmal fields less than that is defined in fraction-digits

Tags: decimalformat, ietf-netmod-yang

I am working with yang (RFC 6020). I have a leaf node 'Frequency' in yang. Frequency field is of type decimal64 and fraction-digits are defined as 6 and range from -90.000000 to 90.000000.
While trying to validate and save, following happens:

1. Number with 6 decimals gets saved eg. 34.000001
2. Number with no decimals gets saved eg. 34

But when I try to save number with decimal value less then 6 digits,
it doesn't get saved. It gives following error:
eg.

- 34.1: 
      "wrong fraction-digits 1 for type decimal64"
- 34.001 : 
      "wrong fraction-digits 3 for type decimal64"
- 34.00001 : 
      "wrong fraction-digits 5 for type decimal64"

Tried to search on net. Not much document is available on this.
Tried playing around with range parameter but it does not work.

```
leaf Frequency {
    description "Frequency";
    type decimal64 {
        fraction-digits 6;
        range "-90.000000..90.000000";
    }
    default 0;
}
```

I expect to be able to save values with/without decimal values where no of decimal values can vary from 0 to 6 digits. eg. 34, 34.1, 34.0004, 34.000001 etc

Answer (score 1):

The value space for a decimal64 YANG type value with fraction-digits set to 6 are real numbers in the following range: `-9223372036854.775808..9223372036854.775807`. `34`, `34.1`, `34.001`, `34.004`, `34.00001` are all within this range and therefore valid values.

This is what the RFC says about decimal64 built-in type ([RFC6020, Section 9.3, p1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-9.3)):

> The decimal64 type represents a subset of the real numbers, which can
> be represented by decimal numerals.  The value space of decimal64 is
> the set of numbers that can be obtained by multiplying a 64-bit
> signed integer by a negative power of ten, i.e., expressible as
> "i x 10^-n" where i is an integer64 and n is an integer between 1 and
> 18, inclusively.

So basically, `d x 10^f`, where `d` is a decimal64 value and `f` is fraction-digits, must result in a valid int64 value, which [ranges](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-9.2) from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusively.

Here is how fraction-digits is defined ([RFC6020, Section 9.3.4, p1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-9.3.4)):

> The "fraction-digits" statement, which is a substatement to the
> "type" statement, MUST be present if the type is "decimal64".  It
> takes as an argument an integer between 1 and 18, inclusively.  It
> controls the size of the minimum difference between values of a
> decimal64 type, by restricting the value space to numbers that are
> expressible as "i x 10^-n" where n is the fraction-digits argument.

> The following table lists the minimum and maximum value for each
> fraction-digit value:

> ```
> +----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
> | fraction-digit | min                   | max                  |
> +----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
> | 1              | -922337203685477580.8 | 922337203685477580.7 |
> | 2              | -92233720368547758.08 | 92233720368547758.07 |
> | 3              | -9223372036854775.808 | 9223372036854775.807 |
> | 4              | -922337203685477.5808 | 922337203685477.5807 |
> | 5              | -92233720368547.75808 | 92233720368547.75807 |
> | 6              | -9223372036854.775808 | 9223372036854.775807 |
> | 7              | -922337203685.4775808 | 922337203685.4775807 |
> | 8              | -92233720368.54775808 | 92233720368.54775807 |
> | 9              | -9223372036.854775808 | 9223372036.854775807 |
> | 10             | -922337203.6854775808 | 922337203.6854775807 |
> | 11             | -92233720.36854775808 | 92233720.36854775807 |
> | 12             | -9223372.036854775808 | 9223372.036854775807 |
> | 13             | -922337.2036854775808 | 922337.2036854775807 |
> | 14             | -92233.72036854775808 | 92233.72036854775807 |
> | 15             | -9223.372036854775808 | 9223.372036854775807 |
> | 16             | -922.3372036854775808 | 922.3372036854775807 |
> | 17             | -92.23372036854775808 | 92.23372036854775807 |
> | 18             | -9.223372036854775808 | 9.223372036854775807 |
> +----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
> ```

The tool you are using is wrong. The following is valid YANG:

```
  typedef foobar {
    type decimal64 {
      fraction-digits 6;
      range "-90.000000..90.000000";
    }
    default 34.00001;
  }
```

YANG 1.1 ([RFC7950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-9.3)) did not change this aspect of the language (the same applies).